# findAll not supported in this implementation of GORM

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I'm trying to test a method in my service but I keep getting error that

> String-based queries like [findAll] are currently not supported in this
>   implementation of GORM. Use criteria instead.

My service:

```
class MyService {
  List<Color> colorShade (String shade) {
    def shadeId = Shade.findByName(shade).id
    return ColorShade.get(shadeId)      
  }
}
```

My class that joins `Shade` and `Color` domains

```
class ColorShade extends Serializable {
  Color color
  Shade shade
  static ColorShade create (Color color, Shade shade, boolean flush = false) {
    if (get(shade.id) == null)
        new ColorNetwork(color: color, shade: shade).save(flush:  flush)
  }

   static ColorShade get (long shadeId) {
        ColorShade.findAll 'from ColorShade where shade.id = :shadeId',
                [shadeId: shadeId]
    }
    static mapping = {
        table 'color_shade'
        version false
        id composite: ['color', 'shade']
    }
}
```

My Spec: `test\unit\MyServiceSpec.groovy` I've also tried adding it to `test\integration\MyServiceSpec.groovy`

```
@TestFor(MyServiceSpec)
@Mock([Color, Shade, ColorNetwork])
@TestMixin(DomainClassUnitTestMixin)
class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {

    def shade
    def color
  def setup(){
    color = new Color(name: "red")
    shade = new Shade(name: "dark")
    color.save(flush: true)
    shade.save(flush: true)

    ColorShade.create(color, shade)
    /* 
    I've also tried:
    mockDomain(ColorShade, [[color: color, shade: shade]])
    but I get the same error
    */

  }
  def cleanup () {
  }

  def "test colorShade" () {
    expect:
       1 == service.colorShade("dark").size()
  }
}
```

When I run this test I get an error:

```
String-based queries like [findAll] are currently not supported in this implementation of GORM. Use criteria instead.
```

**Question**

- How can I test this ? I am on grails 2.2.4

Note: This is just a sample test scenario I've created for purpose of the question. My actual tests are different but in them I have the same problem as this question.

Comment: The title "How to use dynamic finders in unit tests in grails?" doesn't sound appropriate.  The dynamic finder should be fine.  It is the call to `findAll` that is the problem.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether it is the dynamic finder or the static methods? but you are correct....I can use dynamic finders on `Color` and `Shade` classes.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I've changed the title. I have complex logic in my service that is dependent on `Color`, `Shade`, and `ColorShade` that I would like to write test cases for so that I can stop opening old bugs while fixing new ones. Appreciate your help

Comment: Your question includes a bunch of stuff that unnecessarily complicates the question and includes enough goofy stuff that I think answering it will only contribute to confusion.

Comment: i will try to create a sample repo on github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using version 4.3.5.4 or later of the hibernate4 plugin then you can use the `grails.test.mixin.hibernate.HibernateTestMixin`, which supports a full Hibernate GORM in your unit test environment.  You need to add that as a dependency with something like this in `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`.

```
dependencies {
    test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4"
}
```

Then annotate your test with the `grails.test.mixin.hibernate.HibernateTestMixin` annotation.

Comment: The original question says that he is using Grails 2.2.4 so I don't think you are going to be able to use HibernateTestMixin. Probably the simplest thing to do if you really have to organize your code in the way that is described in the description is to just do some simple meta programming in your test like `ColorShade.metaClass.static.get = { long id -> // return a List of ColorShade here, don't involve the db }`.

Comment: I get some other error if I add that dependency. I've created a simple grails app here https://github.com/Omnipresent/testservice

Comment: There are many methods in my class which I'll need to write meta programming for. Plus if I do meta programming then if I change some logic in my `ColorShade` class then that has to be replicated elsewhere in the test cases too....I'm really trying to find the right way to do this (and learn). I assume this is common practice..

Comment: String based queries have not had real unit testing support in the framework until recently.  There isn't going to be a great solution for Grails 2.2.x.

Comment: The app that you linked is attempting to use the HibernateTestMixin, which is not going to work.  As I stated in my note earlier, that will work if you are using the hibernate4 plugin (not the hibernate plugin) version 4.3.5.4 or later.

Comment: Thanks - I've been thinking about upgrading to get the REST support maybe this will give me a push. Which version has support for String based queries for unit testing? I will try the hibernate 4.3.5.4 or later plugin

Comment: I think hibernate4 version 4.3.5.4 requires Grails 2.3.5 or later.